# Struggling with making a plugin extension for woocommerce subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am trying to create a **product calendar** for my WordPress + WooCommerce e-shop. Every month the user will receive a product of his choice based on his product calendar, where he can choose products. The problem is, some products are premium and add extra cost to the subscription.

`standard subscription/month + extra product price`

`30$/month + 15$` ("15$" extra product price can change every month based on the product selection for that month)

I guess, I am inexperienced with wordpress plugin creation since i am unable to create this plugin on my own, but i am sure that this is possible since,
**you can edit the subscription price of an existing subscription in the admin menu**. i thought about hijacking the function from the admin panel using requests, really messy). if anyone dares to tackle this issue, i would also like a way to test it since i don't have a month to wait. first time creating a stack overflow article, have mercy! :)

what i've tried:

- reading woocommerce docs - really unclear what was for developers. i couldn't find any mention on subscription's hook functions, which is what i was after.
- hook functions - didn't know what functions handled subscription so i couldn't hook my code to it.
- use the woocommerce API - on my development wordpress i am getting a permanent 401, and i don't think the soluton will be there anyway, and also messy.
- hijack wordpress admin menu - on the admin panel you can change the subscription price, so capturing the request and editing it could work but this is extremely messy and dumb.
- trying to reverse engineer the php plugin code - I wasn't able to find the functions responsible, i am inexperienced in this.
- trying to edit the databse - if i could edit the database of the subscription price i could make a working demo, but after searching the entire wp databse, i found nothing and changing values seemingly did nothing.

---

### Edit:

I believe i have solved the issue and i want to post the solution since i don't want anyone to go through what i went through. Woocommerce manages subscriptions, orders and almost everything using pages. for example when you receive an order a new page gets created with it's properties (price, customer, etc.) being assigned in the page's metadata. here is a demo that lists all the pages and metadata:

```php
<?php
     function list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_shortcode() {
        global $wpdb;
    
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
        $query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE post_type = 'shop_subscription'";
    
        $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
    
        if ($results) {
            $output = '<ul>';
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $output .= '<li>';
                $output .= '<strong><a href="' . admin_url('post.php?post=' . $result->ID . '&action=edit') . '">' . $result->post_title . '</a></strong>';
                
                // Get and display subscription metadata
                $metadata = get_post_meta($result->ID);
                if (!empty($metadata)) {
                    $output .= '<ul>';
                    foreach ($metadata as $key => $value) {
                        $output .= '<li><strong>' . $key . ':</strong> ' . implode(', ', $value) . '</li>';
                    }
                    $output .= '</ul>';
                } else {
                    $output .= '<p>No metadata found for this subscription.</p>';
                }
                
                $output .= '</li>';
            }
            $output .= '</ul>';
        } else {
            $output = 'No subscription pages found.';
        }
    
        return $output;
    }
    
    add_shortcode('list_subscription_pages_with_metadata', 'list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_shortcode');
    
    // Create an admin menu item for the plugin
    function list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_plugin_menu() {
        add_menu_page(
            'List Subscription Pages with Metadata Plugin',
            'Subscription Pages with Metadata',
            'manage_options',
            'list-subscription-pages-with-metadata-plugin',
            'list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_admin_page'
        );
    }
    
    add_action('admin_menu', 'list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_plugin_menu');
    
    // Callback function to display the admin page
    function list_subscription_pages_with_metadata_admin_page() {
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<h2>List of WooCommerce Subscription Pages with Metadata</h2>';
        echo do_shortcode('[list_subscription_pages_with_metadata]');
        echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Perhaps i am too hot headed, and that stopped me from looking at the
bigger picture, either way it seems very simple now.

Comment: Try to add in your question the best code attempt that you tried, even if it doesn't work… You will get better chances to get some help. Now, I don't think that you can change a subscription amount on the payment gateway itself, as this requires an acceptance by the customer each time. So changing the amount on WooCommerce will not solve the problem in the payment gateway.

Comment: Maybe you could have a variable subscription product, with 2 variations: One "normal" and another "premium". Then the customer could "switch" subscription from "normal" to "premium" paying the difference...